# How to union two tables to override empty values and order by timestamp?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, linq

I have two tables that represent the status of a user along with the timestamp that their status changed. I have something set up like this:

```
StatusTable

user_id          updated_status   timestamp
---------------- ---------------- -----------------------
1617             PENDING          2018-02-21 01:06:01.000
1617             DONE             2018-02-21 01:01:01.000
1617             PENDING          2018-02-06 01:06:01.000


OverrideStatusTable

user_id          updated_status                   timestamp
---------------- -------------------------------- -----------------------
1617                                              2018-02-23 08:12:40.297
1617             DONE-A                           2018-02-14 15:10:49.717
1617             DONE-B                           2018-02-14 15:10:35.850
1617                                              2018-02-14 15:09:23.973
1617             DONE-A                           2018-02-14 14:59:30.113
```

I'm trying to combine the two tables into one result, ordered by timestamp, in which the values in OverriddeStatusTable override the values in StatusTable, except for when updated_status in OverrideStatus table empty, in which the most recent status from StatusTable shows instead, but with the timestamp on the cleared value from OverrideStatusTable. So I'd want the result of my query to look something like this:

```
user_id          updated_status   timestamp
---------------- ---------------- -----------------------
1617             PENDING          2018-02-23 08:12:40.297
1617             DONE-A           2018-02-14 15:10:49.717
1617             DONE-B           2018-02-14 15:10:35.850
1617             PENDING          2018-02-14 15:09:23.973
1617             DONE-A           2018-02-14 14:59:30.113
1617             PENDING          2018-02-06 01:06:01.000
```

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to do this - keep in mind that I'll eventually be loading these two tables as DataTables in my .NET project and querying them using LINQ. But right now I just want to make sure I get the logic right.

Right now my query is set up like this:

```
select *
from StatusTable
where user_id='1617'
UNION
select *
from OverrideStatusTable
where user_id='1617' and updated_status != ''
order by update_date desc
```

But that doesn't get me anywhere close to what I want. The output of that is:

```
user_id          updated_status                   timestamp
---------------- -------------------------------- -----------------------
1617             PENDING                          2018-02-21 01:06:01.000
1617             DONE                             2018-02-21 01:01:01.000
1617             DONE-A                           2018-02-14 15:10:49.717
1617             DONE-B                           2018-02-14 15:10:35.850
1617             DONE-A                           2018-02-14 14:59:30.113
1617             PENDING                          2018-02-06 01:06:01.000
```

Comment: I don't understand why the row with the time of `2018-02-21 01:06:01.000` in your first table is missing from your expected output. Could you explain?

Comment: @Larnu What do you mean? It's the very last record.

Answer (score 0):

A complete guess, if I'm honest, but perhaps...

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE StatusTable (user_id int,
                          updated_status varchar(10),
                          [timestamp] datetime2(3));
GO
CREATE TABLE OverrideStatusTable (user_id int,
                          updated_status varchar(10),
                          [timestamp] datetime2(3));
GO

INSERT INTO StatusTable
VALUES
(1617             ,'PENDING',          '2018-02-21 01:06:01.000'),
(1617             ,'DONE',             '2018-02-21 01:01:01.000'),
(1617             ,'PENDING',          '2018-02-06 01:06:01.000');

INSERT INTO OverrideStatusTable
VALUES
(1617             ,NULL,                               '2018-02-23 08:12:40.297'),
(1617             ,'DONE-A',                           '2018-02-14 15:10:49.717'),
(1617             ,'DONE-B',                           '2018-02-14 15:10:35.850'),
(1617             ,NULL,                               '2018-02-14 15:09:23.973'),
(1617             ,'DONE-A',                           '2018-02-14 14:59:30.113');
GO
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 1
             user_id,
             updated_status,
             [timestamp]
      FROM StatusTable
      WHERE user_id = 1617
      ORDER BY [Timestamp] ASC) ST
UNION
SELECT user_id,
       ISNULL(updated_status,'PENDING'),
       [timestamp]
FROM OverrideStatusTable OST
WHERE user_id = 1617
ORDER BY [timestamp] DESC;

GO
DROP TABLE StatusTable;
DROP TABLE OverrideStatusTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your results can be obtained with:

```
select ost.userid, ost.status, ost.timestamp
from OverrideStatusTable ost
where status is not null
union all
select ost.userid,
       (select top 1 st.status
        from statustable st
        where st.user_id = ost.user_id and
              st.timetamp <= ost.timestamp
       ) as status,
       ost.timestamp
from OverrideStatusTable ost
where status is null
union all
select st.*
from statustable st
where timestamp > (select max(ost.timestamp) from OverrideStatusTable ost where ost.userid = st.userid);
```